# Turtle graphic not running?

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i'm more of a backend web developer and this is for a friend of mine but i have this issue with turtle where her code wont run and i keep getting syntax errors saying certain things aren't defined. Heres the code

```
    import turtle

    turtle.speed(10)

def blue_circle():
    penup()
    setposition(100,50)
    color("blue")
    begin_fill()
    circle(60)
    end_fill()

def red_circle():
    penup()
    setposition(-100,50)
    color("red")
    begin_fill()
    circle(60,360,4)
    end_fill()

def yellow_half_circle():
    penup()
    setposition(-115,-150)
    color("yellow")
    begin_fill()
    circle(60,180)
    end_fill()

def green_pentagon():
    penup()
    setposition(100,-150)
    left(180)
    color("green")
    begin_fill()
    circle(60,360,5)
    end_fill()

   blue_circle()
   red_circle()
   yellow_half_circle()
   green_pentagon()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It looks like it got messed up when you pasted your code here. Python uses indentation to determine control flow and scope so it's critical to get right. Also I see you're never a `Turtle` like via `t = turtle.Turtle()` for instance. Maybe start way simpler, with some code that works, and expand from there rather than trying to code blind.

Comment: there you go its been fixed and while I do understand what you mean about coding blind I definitely would but as I said i'm more into the backend of web development so i've never done graphical things like this

Comment: Yeah I get you, I mean just like, for example, start with a simple program that draws a line, something that definitely works, and then go from there. Writing a bunch of code you can't test is like having write-only memory.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if you use `import turtle` then you have to use `turtle.penup()`, `turtle.setposition()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `import turtle` then you have to use `turtle.penup()`, `turtle.setposition()`, etc.

```
import turtle

turtle.speed(10)

def blue_circle():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(100,50)
    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(60)
    turtle.end_fill()

def red_circle():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(-100,50)
    turtle.color("red")
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(60,360,4)
    turtle.end_fill()

def yellow_half_circle():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(-115,-150)
    turtle.color("yellow")
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(60,180)
    turtle.end_fill()

def green_pentagon():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(100,-150)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(60,360,5)
    turtle.end_fill()

# --- main ---

blue_circle()
red_circle()
yellow_half_circle()
green_pentagon()

turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

---

Original code would work if you would use `from turtle import *` but `import *` is not preferred ([PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))